# How to draw an image in JFrame?

Tags: java, image, jframe

I am trying to put an image into a JFrame. In the code below, I create a 1020 by 720 rectangle, and I would like to put an image within that rectangle.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Screen extends JFrame
{
    private BufferedImage image;
    public Screen () {   
        super("DVD Screensaver");

        Container container = getContentPane(); 
        setSize(1020, 720);   
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)  {
        int windowHorizantal = 0, windowVerticle = 0;
        windowHorizantal = 1020;
        windowVerticle = 720;

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.fillRect(1, 1, windowHorizantal, windowVerticle);
        try {                
          image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("dvd.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        g.drawImage(image, 50, 50, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Screen prog = new Screen ();
        prog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!", but it does draw the black rectangle. I also can't verify if the code is actually reading my image (dvd.png).

Comment: Please provide a more complete error log and which lines correlate in your code.

Comment: That you are reading the image everytime  is already a problem - but if you know where your image is give it there!